# Change the value of the final variable

Tags: android, flutter, dart, overriding

I have two files. In second files I have two classes - StatefulWidget and State.

files1.dart:

```
(...)
Clothes _myClothes;
Widget _buildForm() {
    return ClothesForm(clothes: _myClothes);
  }
(...)
```

To the StatefulWidget class from another file I am sending the clothes variable, which is the Clothing object.

file2:

```
class ClothesForm extends StatefulWidget {
 final Clothes clothes;

  const ClothesForm({Key key, this.clothes
  }) : super(key: key);



  @override
  _ClothesFormState createState() => _ClothesFormState();
    
}
```

In the State class I would like to change the value of the variable clothes - for example widget.clothes.color = red, so that the file from which this variable was sent also sees this change.

```
class _ClothesFormState extends State<ClothesForm> {
   widget.clothes.color = red
}
```

Obviously, I can't do this because it is a final variable.

Question - how can I do this so that the change is visible in the original file1 and variable _myClothes had a new value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a workaround...

How it works:

- Create a callback function with a Clothe parameter in your `ClothesForm`.
- Call the function anytime you want to update/change the `clothes` such that the changes are visible in file 1.
- Implement the function in your file 1 to and set _myClothes to the clothe (The parameter of the function).

#### Implementation

```
class ClothesForm extends StatefulWidget {
 final Clothes clothes;
 final Function(Clothes clothes) onUpdateClothe;

  const ClothesForm({Key key, this.clothes, this.onUpdateClothe
  }) : super(key: key);



  @override
  _ClothesFormState createState() => _ClothesFormState();
}

class _ClothesFormState extends State<ClothesForm> {
   widget.clothes.color = red

   @override
   void initState(){
     super.initState();
     Clothes clotheUpdate = widget.clothes..color = red;
     widget.onUpdateClothe(clotheUpdate);
   }
}
```

```
(...)
Clothes _myClothes;
Widget _buildForm() {
    return ClothesForm(
          clothes: _myClothes,
          onUpdateClothe: (newClothe){
               setState(() => _myClothes = newClothe);
          }
    );
  }
(...)
```

Comment: great solution and perfectly described - thank you very much!